# SFTP using WinSCP .NET timeouts in C# when connecting to port 2222

Tags: c#, ssh, sftp, winscp, winscp-net

I can connect to SFTP using the FileZilla in a machine, in the same machine when I try to connect via C# code it gives error as

> Network error: Connection to "fs2.comparethemarket.com" timed out

SFTP port used for connection;**2222**

Code I am using

```
SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions();
if (_strftpprotocol=="SFTP")
{
    sessionOptions.Protocol = WinSCP.Protocol.Sftp; 
}
else if(_strftpprotocol == "FTP")
{
    sessionOptions.Protocol = WinSCP.Protocol.Ftp;
    sessionOptions.FtpSecure = FtpSecure.Explicit;
}
sessionOptions.HostName = _strftpURL;
sessionOptions.UserName = _strftpUserName;
sessionOptions.Password = _strftpPassword;

if (_strftpprotocol == "SFTP")
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_strftpSSHKey))
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_strftpKeyPath))
        {
            sessionOptions.GiveUpSecurityAndAcceptAnySshHostKey = true;

        }
        else
        {
            privatekeyFilePath = privatekeyFilePath + _strftpKeyPath;
            sessionOptions.SshPrivateKeyPath = privatekeyFilePath;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_strFTPPrivateKeyPassphrase))
            {
                sessionOptions.PrivateKeyPassphrase = _strFTPPrivateKeyPassphrase;
            }
            
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_strFTPSshHostKeyFingerprint))
            {
                sessionOptions.SshHostKeyFingerprint = _strFTPSshHostKeyFingerprint;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_strftpKeyPath))
        {
            sessionOptions.SshHostKeyFingerprint = _strftpSSHKey;
        }
        else
        {
            privatekeyFilePath = privatekeyFilePath + _strftpKeyPath;
            sessionOptions.SshPrivateKeyPath = privatekeyFilePath;
            
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_strFTPPrivateKeyPassphrase))
            {
                sessionOptions.PrivateKeyPassphrase = _strFTPPrivateKeyPassphrase; 
            }
            
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_strFTPSshHostKeyFingerprint))
            {
                sessionOptions.SshHostKeyFingerprint = _strFTPSshHostKeyFingerprint; 
            }
            
        }
    } 
}


Session session = new Session();
session.Open(sessionOptions);
```

Please guide me what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [WinSCP Docs](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_sessionoptions),
[image: win scp docs]
Specifying the `Dst Port` the SFTP Client tries to connect to is done through setting the `sessionOptions` `Port Number` property.
It's necessary only if the server listens on a non-default port (22), which in your case, it is. (2222).

**So to solve your timeout issue,**
set the `Dst Port` with `SessionOptions.PortNumber=2222` (or better yet, save it in a conf file or wherever those other variables (Hostname, username,password) are being set)